# Can't fetch c-namespace and p-namespace for my bean XML configuration file

Tags: xml, spring, configuration

I recently started some spring tutorial. When I try to add c-namespace and p-namespace in my XML configuration file and fetch it form external resources Im getting the error.

I tried to go to the link where should it be but I'm getting 404, I couldn't find it elsewhere to include it form local file. I didn't find any info about migration or anything else.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>Spring</artifactId>
    <groupId>drusil</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>InsideBeans</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: What tutorial are you using?

Comment: On youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osbcbcnQ3Xw&t=533s
Its 4 years old so my first thing was, something change in spring since then but I couldn't find it anywhere